# VS 2017 ASP.Net project doesn't show errors in browser window

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I'm developing a mini project using asp.net in visual studio 2017 community edition.

When there is an error in my code, browser window doesn't show what are the errors. It only shows a blank page. Since I'm new to web development using asp.net, this makes it very difficult to debug the code.

I've seen lot of developers have suggested to edit the web.config page. However there is no web.config page in VS2017.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET are you using? Is it ASP.NET Core 2?

Comment: @James Nope.. still 1.1

Comment: Debug or Release? And have you got `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` in your Startup.cs?

Comment: In Debug.. yes I have it in startup.cs

Comment: Have you used any Exception Filters Attributes ?

Comment: @Nipuna Dilhara, Do you create the general ASP.NET project? As far I know,i t really has the web.cong file for the general default ASP.NET web project. How did you run your app, debugging(F5) or Start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)? Whether it has the same result if you run it using these two ways? As you said you create a mini project, whether your start up item (.aspx file) was blank? If not, how do you know that your project has the errors? Please visit the Output window or the Error list window, maybe you could get some information there.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like issue with VS2017 it self! [Error List Window](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/8487/error-list-window.html).

> When a build fails, the error list window won't be shown if you have
>   the setting to "show output window when build starts" turned off, and
>   you have not yet manually shown the error list window (View => Error
>   list). The build will fail but no error list window.

And as per the updated comments..it has been fixed in current release.

Comment: My VS version is not the latest one which comes with asp.net core 2.0. But it's not that much outdated. I installed to my new laptop a few weeks ago. However, any idea to fix my issue by doing some changes in settings?

Answer (score 0):

While configuring middleware, sequence of statements matter.
Try putting `app.UseMvc()` after Exception blocks.

You can try error pages for different status codes, this may help you. 
https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/StatusCodePage/StatusCodePagesExtensions.cs